# Rails app config.eager_load set to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

During `cap <env> deploy` I get the following error, but all my environment files are set accordingly. What is the deal?

> config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
>
> - development - set it to false
> - test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
> - production - set it to true

UPDATE:
I believe this is because capistrano is not pulling down the latest changes from the branch. Does capistrano cache the branch somewhere? I believe this is the case because the latest release which was 10 minutes ago doesn't include my most recent changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was happening because the repo directory is kind of like a cache...I guess. I just removed it via `rm -rf repo` and then re-deployed.